# Is there an add-on that allows me to create groups that are matched according to one or more criteria?

Tags: r, match

I want to compare two groups of subjects (0,1) but want to make sure that the differences I observe aren't due to a third variable, which is significantly different between the two groups. Group 1 is much smaller than group 0 so I guess it would be optimal to select a subset of subjects from group 0 that best matches the third variable between groups. In a perfect world I guess the add-on would select a subset from both groups that would both maximize the number of subjects and match the third variable between groups. Is there any add-on available that helps me do that. If not, you guys might know an efficient way to achieve the same by some clever coding. Of course it would be even better if I could match the groups over some similarity parameter based on a multitude of variables.

Comment: as @romunov pointed out to me, the matchit package should get you there.

Comment: I'm unclear: in what ways is this a bad question?  It's not worded particularly skillfully from a statistical perspective, but it seems more relevant to SO than statistics.SE.  On the other hand, this doesn't have a lot of detail about example data and the statistical aims, regardless of the wording.  Mike: It might be better to get your head around the statistical question first, on statistics.SE; you may resolve the package issue there, too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `sampling` package. I believe it is the most full featured for doing these types of things. Anyway, here is a worked example:

```
require(sampling)
set.seed(12345)

# Set number of subjects
n = 1000

# Generate data
group = factor(sample(c(0,0,1), n, replace=T))
x = 0.2 * as.numeric(group) + rnorm(n)

data = data.frame(group, x)

# Demonstrate the significant group effect
summary(lm(x ~ group, data=data))

# Let's say we want a sample with 50 subjects in each group
pik = inclusionprobastrata(as.numeric(data$group), c(50, 50))
picks = balancedstratification(cbind(data$x), as.numeric(data$group), pik)

# Pick out our balanced sample
new.data = data[picks==1, ]

# Demonstrate that the group effect is gone
summary(lm(x ~ group, data=new.data))
```